# Applet hangs in IE during security phase

Tags: java, security, internet-explorer, applet

The applet is in a signed JAR.  Last line in console reads:

```
security: Checking if certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
```

CPU and memory usage are normal.  Other page elements still respond.  It's just that the applet is not displayed.

There is another applet in the same page but it works.

Any ideas?

Thread dump follows:

```
Dump thread list ...
Group main,ac=15,agc=3,pri=10
    main,5,alive
    AWT-Shutdown,5,alive
    AWT-Windows,6,alive,daemon
    traceMsgQueueThread,5,alive,daemon
    CacheCleanUpThread,5,alive,daemon
    AWT-EventQueue-0,6,alive
    Thread-9,5,alive
Group Plugin Thread Group,ac=3,agc=0,pri=10
    AWT-EventQueue-1,6,alive
    ConsoleWriterThread,6,alive,daemon
    TimerQueue,5,alive,daemon
Group file:/c:/project/lib/-threadGroup,ac=2,agc=0,pri=4
    thread applet-OsApplet,4,alive
    AWT-EventQueue-2,4,alive
Group file:/c:/project/html/-threadGroup,ac=3,agc=0,pri=4
    thread applet-javax.swing.JApplet.class,4,alive
    TimerQueue,4,alive,daemon
    AWT-EventQueue-3,4,alive
Done.
```

Comment: Does it work with other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.  Applet is sized relatively but containing DIV is not sized explicitly.  When DIV's height CSS property was set, IE rendered the applet.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the applet console (Right click on the small Java icon on your taskbar assuming you are on Windows, or selecting 'View Console' from the browser's menu if Linux). Press 't' to take a thread dump. That would give you more information about what the plugin JVM is doing.

Comment: Thanks!  Updated question with thread dump output.  Seems to me that the applet's thread has exited.  OsApplet is that other applet that's working.  That javax.swing.JApplet is a plain dummy applet.

Answer (score 0):

Getting somewhere.  Applet loads fine when I rearrange my HTML.  Should've mentioned that the applet is loaded via writeln calls to document.  Now the script tag that does this is buried under several div and table tags.  When I moved up the script tag to just after the body tag, the applet appeared.

Know of any IE (or IE and CSS) quirk that might be causing this?

Comment: None that I know of - but if it's IE only, then one possibility can be that you are using OBJECT (instead of EMBED in Firefox) and your previous applets OBJECT tags are somehow interfering due to some unknown IE bug. You can try moving the other applet above and below this to see if that affects.